# NestJS GraphQL subscriptions not working with `graphql-ws`

Tags: graphql, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions

I'm trying to upgrade our NestJS GraphQL subscriptions server to utilize `graphql-ws` rather than the current `subscriptions-transport-ws` (as suggested by the [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions)).
I upgraded the NestJS version to

```
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^9.0.4",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.6",
    "graphql": "^15.5.3",
    "graphql-tools": "^8.2.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.3.0",
```

And after, I added the `subscriptions` option to the `App.Module`:

```
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      sortSchema: true,
      playground: true,
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      subscriptions: {
        'graphql-ws': true
      },
    }),
```

However when I subscribe (in playground) to a previously working subscription, I get:

```
{
  "error": "Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://localhost:8880/graphql. Please check if the endpoint url is correct."
}
```

And in the console I get:

```
WebSocket protocol error occured. It was most likely caused due to an unsupported subprotocol "graphql-ws" requested by the client. graphql-ws implements exclusively the "graphql-transport-ws" subprotocol, please make sure that the client implements it too.
```

Things I have tried:

- Adding the `graphql-ws` package
- Upgrading the NestJS version again
- Removing the `installSubscriptionHandlers` option from config
- Setting `graphql-ws` configs instead of passing `true`
- Using the `WebSocket Test Client` Google Chrome extension instead of Playground

But none have worked. Sorry for the long post. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the time of release of Apollo Server 3, the protocol used in the graphql-ws library is not yet supported by GraphQL Playground or Apollo Explorer.

see [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#the-graphql-ws-transport-library)

It's only advisable to use graphql-ws if interacting with subscriptions via playground is not of much use to you and you're okay interacting with subscriptions solely from your own client that has been setup to use graphql-ws.

To setup your client to use graphql-ws with Apollo. see [here](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws#apollo-client).

Comment: Oh well, that's disappointing. So the Google Chrome extension failed for the same reason as well?

Answer (score 12):

This will do the job:

```
subscriptions: {
    'graphql-ws': true,
    'subscriptions-transport-ws': true,
  },
```

As mentionned in the [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions):

> HINT
>
> You can also use both packages (subscriptions-transport-ws and graphql-ws) at > the same time, for example, for backward compatibility.